# House Symbol in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

What does the house symbol next to variables in LabVIEW mean? e.g. See below:

[image]

Comment: Note that in the example pictured, it is indeterminate whether the values in `String`, `Display` and `Array` will be cleared by the local variable writes before or after the value in `String` is written to `Display` and `Array`. If this is from an actual program, don't do it like this (the simplest improvement would be to put the code with the control and indicator terminals inside the False case of the case structure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means "local" - because it is visible and usable in the current VI scope (kind of a "house" or "home" for that variable). If you check icon of Global variables, they have icon of a "globe" - thus it means that their accessibility scope is the entire application.

Comment: I am somewhat pleased that someone had to ask this question. It means people are going a while using LabVIEW without creating local variables themselves! (Use of variables breaks the dataflow and often leads to problems in code, from simple performance issues to more complex race conditions. They're unhygenic, in the functional programming sense of that term.)

Comment: @srm I'm obliged to respond with what I believe are the two acceptable use cases for local variables: (1) one-to-many communication (one control or indicator, several local variables in read mode) and (2) many-to-one communication (one control or indicator, several local variables in write mode). In both cases the communication is lossy i.e. only the latest value will be received and any changes between reads will be lost. If any of those don't apply, look at another solution instead e.g. notifiers, queues, functional globals, channel wires, etc.

Comment: @srm Also, you're assuming this is not because they're all using Value property nodes instead ;-)

Comment: @nekomatic hope springs eternal.

Comment: @nekomatic in the cases you name for good use of locals, I’d agree were it not for the Tag channel wire, which has the same behavior but allows you to prove there’s only one writer and follow the wire to all its destinations... and make subVIs as needed.

Comment: At least in the past, writing to local variable was much faster that writing to the indicator or the value property. Though I agree, one should be careful using them.

Comment: Writing to local variable can't be - and have never been - faster than to indicator, b/c it uses additional layer. First it updates variable itself, and then - indicator. The fastest is indicator, then local, and then property node. And somewhere close to writing to an indicator is "Set Control Values by Index" function.